# What are the advantages of 7x7 ArUco markers compared to 4x4

Tags: opencv, vision, aruco

I've been using ArUco markers for a while now but I've only ever used the 4x4 markers / dictionaries and I'm just wondering what are the advantages of using say 5x5,6x6 or 7x7?

I would have assumed that the markers with bigger matrices would be able to represent more numbers but it seems that no matter the size the max number is 1000 markers?

Is the only purpose so that you could have 2000 markers if you used both say 4x4 and 5x5 libraries for example?

I've tried googling this but I can't find anything which answers my question.

Comment: I have worked with Aruco markers. The size of their resolution (meaning quantity of squares) is not relevant at first. The size of the marker when it is printed will have a huge impact on your results (distance from camera, no marker dented and so on). The only advantage I can think of to go from a 4x4 to a 7x7 marker is just to have more possibilities. But one thing I found out is that using a bigger size of marker leads you to a little more challenging issues in terms of image processing. My advice is to try to go with the simplest way.